# Automatic NugetPackage upload to Nuget feed

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-server

Is it possible to automatically upload a Nuget package to a feed when building a project using Visual Studio 2017 and .net core?

I can check the option to automatically generate the package, but I don't know how to automate the publish process.

Thanks!

Comment: NuGet command line has the `push` verb, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#push

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to automatically upload a Nuget package to a feed when building a project using Visual Studio 2017 and .net core?

The answer is yes. Since NuGet Command Line Interface (CLI) provides the full extent of NuGet functionality to install, create, **publish**, and manage packages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#push

We could add a **target to execute the publish command line after Visual Studio generate package**. In addition, when you check the option to automatically generate the package, you can notice that the target which generate the package is "`GenerateNuspec`" (MSBuild project build output verbosity->Detailed). So we could a target after the target "`GenerateNuspec`"

```
<Target Name="PushNuGetPackage" AfterTargets="GenerateNuspec">
```

Right click project->Select Edit `projectname.csproj`->Add below scripts:

```
  <Target Name="PushNuGetPackage" AfterTargets="GenerateNuspec">
    <Message Text="Push NuGet Package to NuGet Feed" Importance="high"></Message>
    <Exec Command="D:\nuget.exe push $(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\AutoPushNuGetPackageTest.1.0.0.nupkg -Source D:\LocalServer"></Exec>
  </Target>
```

Note: The exec command should be:

```
<Exec Command="PathOfYourNuGet\nuget.exe push PathOfYourPackage\PackageName.nupkg -Source NuGetFeedPath"></Exec>
```

With this target, Visual Studio will automatically upload a Nuget package to a feed when building a project using Visual Studio:

[image]