# How to automate NuGet pack and publish in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, version

Looking for the solution which allow us to automate NuGet package deployment process. At the moment "Pack" option just builds package, but everything else needs to be done manually. I would like to have these steps built into this new "Pack and Deploy" task:

1. Increment Package version - Something similar to "npm version patch"
2. Builg package
3. Push just created package to the NuGet repository

Maybe someone has done this already and could share experiences?

---

After more research found how to Push after packing: [Automating Nuget Package Push With .NetCore RC2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37389094/2046034)

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Increment Package version - Something similar to "npm version patch"

Before answering this question, we need to know some info about the `AssemblyVersion`, `AssemblyInformationalVersion` and NuGet version, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151226/nuspec-how-to-trim-version-down-to-major-minor-build-semversion) for some details. Then you will know that:

**Nuget doesn’t use either `AssemblyVersion` or `AssemblyFileVersion` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. It uses a third versioning attribute: `AssemblyInformationalVersion`.**

Nuget actually applys whatever is in that string as the package version. So, to increment package version, we need to manually add following code in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("2.0.0")]
```

So, when we need to release a new version package, we just need to update the value of `AssemblyInformationalVersion` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

> 2. Build package

The answer for this question depends on the style of your project, the old project style or the new project style(VS2017-SDK).

Source [Old csproj to new csproj: Visual Studio 2017 upgrade guide](https://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/)

**When you're in the old style project:**

You can just pack the nuget package automatically by a post-build event:

```
$(PathOfYourNuGet)\nuget.exe pack "$(ProjectPath)"
```

With this build event, MSBuild will create the nuget package automatically when you build the project.

**When you in the New style project:**
In the new style project, packagin nuget package becomes very easy. Just check the checkbox `Generate NuGet packafe on build` on package tab of the project properties:

[image]

Note: When you are in the new style project, you can increment package version in the Package version on the package tab.

> 3. Push just created package to the NuGet repository

Just as you found, after publishing the nuget package automatically, you can add a custom target to push it:

```
  <Target Name="PushNuGetPackage" AfterTargets="GenerateNuspec">
    <Message Text="Push NuGet Package to NuGet Feed" Importance="high"></Message>
    <Exec Command="$(PathOfYourNuGet)\nuget.exe push $(TargetDir)\xxx.1.0.0.nupkg -Source NuGetrepository"></Exec>
  </Target>
```

Source [Automatic NugetPackage upload to Nuget feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310745/automatic-nugetpackage-upload-to-nuget-feed/46313070#46313070)

Note: You can not push the nuget package with same name and same version to the nuget.org.

Comment: You are not answering the question.  The OP wants an *automated* method to increment the package version and then push the resulting package to the repository.  *Automated* meaning not sitting at the keyboard and editing files and rolling thought multiple steps.  The OP already knows how to do all this.  What the OP wants is to push a button to (1) increment version (2) build (3) push.  This is not either trivial or obvious and nothing in your well informed answer illuminates this path.